# Docker/ECR - image could not be accessed on a registry to record its digest

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

Environment:  Docker swarm, jenkins doing the builds, and pushing them to ECR.  ECR Access is configured via config.json  Images are tagged with gitbranch-jenkinsbuildnumber .  So :latest is not involved.  The image eventually pulls.  I never issue a docker login command, since the config.json handles it

config.json

```
{
    "credHelpers": {
        "xxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
    }
}
```

log from jenkins

```
+ docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml service-name --with-registry-auth
Updating service service-name (id: 0lpdvnwkrbwslpbc2fqfe9o0y)
image xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bots:16-dev could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bots:16-dev independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

docker pull

```
docker pull xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bots:16-dev
Digest: sha256:088a0c65b06fa178f6950be5f27cf7d29918fb614a41ba67351e5106dccc57cc
Status: Downloaded newer image for xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bots:16-dev
```

I thought it was maybe a timing thing, since we push to ECR, and then deploy from ECR.  I added a 60 second wait post push, and the issue still exists.

Comment: did you manage to find the problem ? if yes how did you solve it ?

Comment: No. Moved off of ecr.